# Invoking error function in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I want to invoke error function in xslt 2.0 on a specific condition but i don't know the syntax to do this .

Please explain with an example.

Please check this code in the XSLT :

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space($vehicle/VIN)) != 17"> error(QName('Invalid VIN')) </xsl:if>
```

Comment: This question is lacking vital information to diagnose the problem, to say the least. Include XML input and output, your XLST code and explain what problem you are facing.

Comment: I want to stop processing the input xml and throw an error whenever a specific condition in the xsl file is met e.g. I am checking the length of a variable from the input xml and if its length != 10 , i want to raise an error. Have you understood my query ?

Comment: I understood perfectly well. But I'm not sure whether you've understood _my_ "query": "Include XML input and output, your XLST code and explain what problem you are facing." Explain the _problem_, not your solution to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Sample Input xml: http://pastebin.com/nPaEP5yT                             Sample XSLT : http://pastebin.com/Knx1hvEk                                Please check this code in the XSLT :                          <xsl:if test="string-length(normalize-space($vehicle/VIN)) != 17">
                                                                               
                        error(QName('Invalid VIN'))
                       
                </xsl:if>

Answer (score 2):

Use e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="if (string-length(normalize-space($vehicle/VIN)) != 17) then error(QName('http://example.com/', 'some-error-code'), 'Invalid VIN') else ()"/>`.